# find $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^2y^2}{x^4+y^4}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

if $$f(x,y)=\frac{x^2y^2}{x^4+y^4}$$ is a 2 variable function, find $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^2y^2}{x^4+y^4}$$

I really don't understand 2 variable limits. I understand that if limits from 2 or more paths aren't the same, the limit doesn't exist, but I don't know how to find the limit since there is an infinite number of paths possible.

Comment: If it doesn't exist then often you've just got to guess a class of paths cleverly.  In this case, try paths of the form $y=mx$.

Comment: And if it does exist?

Comment: For those cases you hope that you can somehow reduce it to a one dimensional limit through changes of variables.  Or you might have to go back to the limit definition.  There are probably other strategies as well, but in general finding the limit when it *does* exist is a harder task.  Keep in mind that your professors aren't going to give you something intractible, though.  Many times something simple like a polar transform will do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Approach #1**: $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof...probably too much work for the given problem.

**Approach #2: Convert to polar/spherical**

Recalling that $x=r \cos \theta$ and $y= r \sin \theta$, we note that $(x,y) \to (0,0) \iff r \to 0$. As such,

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0) } \frac{ x^2 y^2}{x^4 + y^4} = \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{r^2 \cos^2 \theta \cdot r^2 \sin ^2 \theta}{r^4 ( \cos^4 \theta + \sin^4 \theta)}=\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{\cos^2 \theta \cdot  \sin ^2 \theta}{ \cos^4 \theta + \sin^4 \theta} =\frac{\cos^2 \theta \cdot  \sin ^2 \theta}{ \cos^4 \theta + \sin^4 \theta} $$
Since the last is expression is a non-constant function of $\theta$ (i.e., doesn't simplify to a constant using trig identities), this means that the limiting value depends on the angle taken to approach $(0,0)$, so there is no way to assign a single value to the limit along all possible paths.

**Approach #3: lines**

Let's look at what happens if we approach $(0,0)$ along lines $y=kx$:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2 y^2}{x^4 + y^4} = \lim_{(x, kx) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2 (kx)^2}{x^4 + (kx)^4} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{k^2 x^4}{x^4 (1+k^4)} = \frac{k^2}{1+k^4}$$ 
Again, we got that the limiting value depended upon path taken to reach $(0,0)$, i.e., the slope of the particular line followed. Therefore, there is no consistent way to define what value $f(x,y)$ should approach near the origin.

**Approach #4: Graph it**

[image: 3D Plot]

Notice that as we approach $(0,0)$ in different directions, we limit on different values between $0$ and $1/2$. There is no way to pick a specific value that all possible curves limit upon.

Answer (score 0):

For a function $f(x,y)$ that is not defined at $x=y=0,$ the def'n of $r=\lim_{x,y\to 0}f(x,y)$ is $$\forall d>0 \;  \exists e>0 \; \forall x,y \; (0<x^2+y^2<e^2\implies |f(x,y)-r|<d).$$ From the details in the answer by erfink, you can see that in this case there is no such $r.$