# Prove $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^2y^2}{x^4+y^4}$ does not exist using $\epsilon,\delta$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

I need to show that $\exists\epsilon>0$ s.t. $\forall\delta>0$, $0<\|(x,y)\|<\delta$ and $|\frac{x^2y^2}{x^4+y^4}-L|\geq\epsilon$ for all $L\in\mathbb{R}$.

Now I try to find such an $\epsilon$, but am unable to do so, and am not sure if I am even using the correct approach to proceed.

To find this $\epsilon$, I try to fix arbitrary $\delta$ and $(x,y)$, and see if I can derive some $\epsilon$ which will satisfy the first statement but cannot figure out how.

Comment: Try looking at the axis $x=0$

Comment: Take $\epsilon = 1/4$ and $x=y=1/N$ for arbitrary large $N$,

Comment: Consider that if $x=y\ne 0$ then $x^2y^2/(x^4+y^4)=1/2$ but if $x=2y\ne 0$ then $x^2y^2/(x^4+y^4)=4/17.$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [find $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^2y^2}{x^4+y^4}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1970422/find-lim-x-y-to-0-0-fracx2y2x4y4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem, where you are (in effect) trying to show that the negation of the $\epsilon,\delta$ definition of a limit holds, is easiest to solve, by first attacking the problem with intuition.

As $(x,y) \to (0,0)$, in any small neighborhood of radius $\delta$ around $(0,0)$ there will be at least one value $(x,y)$ such that $y^2 = kx^2$, where $k$ can be any positive real number.

Therefore, examining the problem intuitively, you have to show that as $k$ varies, the function $f(x,y)$ will critically vary.

$$\frac{x^2y^2}{x^4 + y^4} = \frac{x^4(k)}{x^4(1 + k^2)} = \frac{k}{1 + k^2}.\tag1 $$

Thus, (for example) 
when $k=1$, you have that $\displaystyle \frac{k}{1 + k^2} = \frac{1}{2}$ 
and when $k=2$, you have that $\displaystyle \frac{k}{1 + k^2} = \frac{2}{5}.$

Now, consider that
$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2} \times \left|\frac{1}{2} - \frac{2}{5}\right| = \frac{1}{20}.$

Therefore, suppose that you take $\epsilon = \frac{1}{20}$.

Then, regardless of how small $\delta > 0$ is taken, you will be able to find $2$ points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ within the neighborhood of radius $\delta$ around $(0,0)$ such that 
$|f(x_1,y_1) - f(x_2, y_2)| = 2\epsilon.$

This is game over, by the triangle inequality, regardless of what candidate value of $L$ is suggested.

That is 
$$ |f(x_1,y_1) - L| + |f(x_2,y_2) - L| \geq |f(x_1,y_1) - f(x_2, y_2)| = 2\epsilon.\tag1 $$

Therefore, at least one of the two LHS terms in (1) above must be $\geq \epsilon ~:~$ game over.